# cannot access class com.sun.javafx.print.Units

Tags: javafx

I am trying to print a custom paper ; however , when I create a new paper size with the class PrintHelper to access the private constructor of Paper

```
Paper customPaper = PrintHelper.createPaper("105MMx22MM", 105, 22, Units.MM);
```

I receive the following error message in the console :

```
cannot access class com.sun.javafx.print.Units
```

I am using javafx 11.0.2 , and this is my VM option:

```
-p
"C:\Users\...\AdditionalLib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"
--add-modules
javafx.fxml,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics
```

Answer (score 0):

add `--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.print=ALL-UNNAMED` into VM option should fix the problem .
Generally , if the JavaFX rises some error which looks like :

```
module <javafx.some-module> does not export <some-packet> to unnamed module
```

should be resolved by :

```
--add-exports <javafx.some-module>/<some-packet>=ALL-UNNAMED
```